# Java bigDecimal MySQL (Prepared Statement) decimal lost

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, bigdecimal

My problem is that when I save my `BigDecimal` in database (ex: 22.21) and then we I get it back the `BigDecimal` from the database the decimal is not there anymore (ex: 22).

I have the following query

```
String statement ="INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (amount) VALUES( ? )";
PreparedStatement stmt = DataBase.getInstance().prepareStatement(statement);
//set data
stmt.setBigDecimal(1, payment.getAmount());
// ...
```

Then I get it back the amount from the database this way :

```
String q = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE project=" + project.getId();
//...
payment.setAmount(rs.getBigDecimal("amount")); // <-- decimal is lost
```

The amount in my database is:

```
amount NUMERIC NOT NULL
```

---

**Answer:**

The MySQL Type should be `DECIMAL(x,y)` instead of `NUMERIC`.

*(This solved my problem thank you Andriy)*

Comment: `rs.getInt()` returns an `int`. Use `getBigDecimal()` or `getDouble()`

Comment: yes sorry i was wrong in my code/question fixed

Comment: `payment.getAmount()` what is it returning? int or double?

Comment: Then here you go. fix the return type from that method from int to double.

Comment: did you check if `rs.getBigDecimal("amount")` actually returns 22.11? Maybe there's a type mismatch with your `amount` field in `payment`.

Comment: yes it is NUMERIC? Should it be something else?

Comment: There are two checks you should do, first check if the value stored in the database is 22.11, if it is then the problem must be in your `Payment` object, having an `int`/`Integer` or `long`/`Long` typed field to store the `amount`. About the `NUMERIC` database field, I'd try changing it to `DECIMAL`.

Comment: Ok i am gonna do this Gamb thank you. It was DECIMAL then i switched to NUMERIC

Comment: can you show amount field declaration when you create table? Maybe you should declare it as DECIMAL(10,5) or something. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999582/how-to-insert-decimal-into-mysql-database)

Comment: Yes Andriy you were right thank you