# How to insert/update decimal into mysql via PHPmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, floating-point, decimal

I want to insert/update decimal number to mysql. But everytime I did. It return the round number or truncate dot number. I tried change the datatype of lv_pay and lv_dis either to `decimal` and `double` but still the result.

**MySQL**

`update settings_price_pay set lv_pay='3.2',lv_dis='0' where pset='1' and cate='161a5954c2e7713417906c523204a2be' and ltype='p_rhi'`

**PHPMyadmin**

[image]

Comment: why do you use quotes? Double numbers should be inserted or updated without quotes.

Comment: see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert DECIMAL into MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999582/how-to-insert-decimal-into-mysql-database)

Comment: @MichaelO. - Quoting numeric values does not hurt.

Answer (score 1):

First:

The data type of those numeric fields should be `DECIMAL(12,2)` or something similar, declaring that you use a picture of S#########9.99.  Sign, ten digits, point, two digits.

Second:

Don't put your numbers in `'quotes'`. If you do, MySQL first coerces them to IEEE 64-bit numbers, then to whatever datatype you have for your columns. Say this:

```
set lv_pay=3.2, lv_dis=0
```

Notice that MySQL ignores the numbers in parentheses in `DOUBLE(11,2)` and simply uses a 64-bit IEEE floating point number. (It honors those numbers when you declare a `DECIMAL(12,2)` data type.)

Comment: A new rule for me on mySQL. Thank you very much.

Comment: I haven't see "S#########9.99" since the heydays of COBOL !  What language uses such now?

Comment: None that I know of. It's just an easy way to explain `(12,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer, just for novice like me. Change the 'length/value' of the row (in my case) from `(11,0)` into `(11,2)`. Found it accidentally.

Comment: Do not use `DOUBLE(11,2)`, use `DECIMAL(11,2)`.

Comment: Done, Thank you!